# Symfony Doctrine validation not working with Annotations on Embeddables

Tags: symfony, validation, doctrine

I just wanted to make sure that my *@Assert\NotBlank* on a field in an Embeddable works inside a phpunit-test (using Doctrine 2.7 and Symfony 5.1) but it seems that no check is being made.
To make sure that it's not about the test-env I tested the same thing with an injected validator
on a route on a test-server with the same results. Violations to Assertions on the embedding entity work just fine.

Any suggestions why this might be the case?

So basically:

```
/**
 * @package App\Entity\Embeddables
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 */
class MyEmbeddable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private string $text;
}
```

with

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MyThingRepository::class)
 */
class MyThing
{
    //..ID-stuff
    /**
     * @var MyEmbeddable
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="App\Entity\Embeddables\MyEmbeddable")
     */
    private MyEmbeddable $embeddableTestVar;
}
```

would result in:

```
$myThing = new MyThing();
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator();
dd($validator->validate($myThing));
```

printing an empty array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why the -1? I am pretty sure that someone else who is new to this topic can profit from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the `@Assert\Valid` annotation

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MyThingRepository::class)
 */
class MyThing
{
    //..ID-stuff
    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     *
     * @var MyEmbeddable
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="App\Entity\Embeddables\MyEmbeddable")
     */
    private MyEmbeddable $embeddableTestVar;
}
```